# get underlying type from a specific interface in golang

Tags: go, reflection

As the example, can I get a zero value of its underlying type from the interface Work?

```
func MakeSomething(w Worker){
    w.Work()

    //can I get a zeor value type of The type underlying w?
    //I tried as followed, but failed

    copy :=w
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&copy)
    fm :=v.Elem()
    modified :=reflect.Zero(fm.Type())//fm.type is Worker, and modified comes to be nil
    fm.Set(modified)
    fmt.Println(copy)
}

type Worker interface {
    Work()
}
```

[the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rToji-2SFT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `w` contains a pointer to a `Worker`, you might want to get a zero value of *the element it is pointing to*. Once you get the element, you can create a zero value of its type:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(w).Elem() // Get the element pointed to
zero := reflect.Zero(v.Type()) // Create the zero value
```

Above code snippet will panic if you pass in a non-pointer to `MakeSomething`. To prevent this, you might want to do the following instead:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(w)
if reflect.TypeOf(w).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
zero := reflect.Zero(v.Type())
```

If you actually want to have a pointer to a new `Worker`, you just replace `reflect.Zero(v.Type())` with  `reflect.New(v.Type())`.

Comment: my first question, thank you sincerely~ i found the difference,
 `fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(w).Type())//print *main.Testg` 
 `fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(&w).Type())//print *main.Worker` 
in the case I use the second way(I think this can change the value w point to)

Comment: @linvan You're welcome! Yes, `&w` is quite useless, really. It will give you a pointer to an interface containing a pointer to the value. And you very seldom (never, really) work with pointers to interfaces in Go.